# WPF - modify window content from ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF application. I'm trying to modify it to use the MVVM pattern.

Now, in the code behind of my main window, when I click a button, I change the "Content" of my window with a WebBrowser control :

```
Content = webBrowserWrapper.WebBrowser;
```

I would like to do it from a command in my ViewModel. How can I access the "Content" property of my window ?

If it's not possible, what is the simple way to modify the content of my window (maybe create a new window and navigate to it)

Comment: ViewModel has no knowledge of the View. Never use UI element in ViewModel.

Comment: You could have all the possible "Content" in your xaml already and bind their visibility to properties in your viewmodel. Set the ones not in use to Collapsed. Or, have your viewmodel fire off an event that your view catches which has access to "Content".

Comment: Why dont you use Application.Current.MainWindow.Content ?

Comment: Thx. But how can I have more than one "ContentControl in a view ? It says "The property "Content" is set more than once"

Comment: @N.J : Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I'm a beginner and I didn't know it...

Comment: I meant have multiple grids (or whatever) in the content with each grid's visibility set to a property in the viewmodel. Does that help?

Comment: @user3544117 place your content controls inside a Grid

Answer (score 0):

The principal behind MVVM is that UI is the concern of the View, and logic is the concern of the ViewModel.

You describe a concern of the View, which is properly handled within its codebehind.  There is no need to involve the ViewModel in this action.

So, in other words... congrats.  You're already there.

Comment: Yes, but I had to do some logic before changing the Content. I used "Application.Current.MainWindow.Content" from the ViewModel and it's working, even if that's not a proper way to do it. Maybe I should do like this : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/323187/MVVMLight-Using-Two-Views but with Prism instead of mvvm light...

Comment: @user3544117: That is the opposite of following the MVVM pattern.  Your question doesn't detail what must happen and in what sequence when that button is pressed, so we can't really help you.

Comment: I have a single window. First I have a configuration view with a form, and when I click the "Save" button, I save the configuration in a file and modify the "Content" of the window with a WebBrowser control. Now, I want to do it properly with the mvvm pattern. I should have two views and switch the view when I click the "Save" button. I need to do this : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/323187/MVVMLight-Using-Two-Views but With but I'm using Prism instead of mvvm light and the "ViewModelBase" class doesn't exist...  I will do some search and maybe create a new Post...